# Background: Linear Gradient with IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm new with html and CSS.

I'm doing a table in css with google charts, and i have a code in VFP that creates the file in HTMl with data in SQL.

I want in determinate cell's that have more than one color in background, so i use this code in specific's cell

This works in Firefox, Chrome and Edge, but with IE don't work. What i have to put in code to work with iE?

```
    data.setProperty(2, 10, "background-color", "linear-gradient(to bottom,rgb(231,111,81) 50%,rgb(233,196,106) 50%");
    data.setProperty(2, 10,"style", "background:linear-gradient(to bottom,rgb(231,111,81) 50%,rgb(233,196,106) 50%");
```

Comment: I think this the line you are looking for filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e76f51', endColorstr='#e9c46a',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a prefix for linear gradient use tools like autoprefixer to generate the required css.

https://autoprefixer.github.io/

this doesn't work for IE as it is pretty old you will need to replicate the gradient here.

https://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#e76f51+50,e9c46a+50

remove the comments and you have browser compatible CSS gradient that works almost everywhere.

```
background: #e76f51; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #e76f51 50%, #e9c46a 50%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #e76f51 50%,#e9c46a 50%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #e76f51 50%,#e9c46a 50%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e76f51', endColorstr='#e9c46a',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> data.setProperty(2, 10, "background-color", "linear-gradient(to bottom,rgb(231,111,81) 50%,rgb(233,196,106) 50%");
> data.setProperty(2, 10,"style", "background:linear-gradient(to bottom,rgb(231,111,81) 50%,rgb(233,196,106) 50%");
> ```

The issue is related to the above code, it is invalid, the linear-gradient property miss an end mark (');'). Try to modify the code as below:

```
data.setProperty(2, 10, "background-color", "linear-gradient(to bottom,rgb(231,111,81) 50%,rgb(233,196,106) 50%);");
data.setProperty(2, 10, "style", "background: linear-gradient(to bottom,rgb(231,111,81) 50%, rgb(233,196,106) 50%);");
```

Besides, you could also use data.setCell() method to add css class for the special cell.
like this:

```
data.setCell(2, 1, 8000, '$8,000', { 'className': 'deeppink-border right-text customstyle' });
```

The CSS style:

```
.customstyle {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,rgb(231,111,81) 50%, rgb(233,196,106) 50%);
    background-color: linear-gradient(to bottom,rgb(231,111,81) 50%,rgb(233,196,106) 50%);
}
```